# How to fix less syntaxError when importing from node_modules with next.js

Tags: webpack, less, next.js

So I made a webapp with Create React App, but I want to test out SSR, so I am trying to port it to next.js, but am using a component library, that requires importing `less`-files from node_modules, but doing so gives syntaxerror in the imported file, when running `next build` or `next` and going to one of the pages.

I have already tried: importing from js vs importing from core less file, both gives the same result, I have also tried [this](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/267) with no results, I am using next 9.0.1, but also ran into this issue on next 8. I have also searched both [Next.js's](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) Github issues and PR's, and the [next-plugins](https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins) repo, without finding any working fix.

This is my next.config.js:

```js
const withLess = require("@zeit/next-less");
const withImages = require("next-images");

module.exports = withImages(
  withLess({
    cssModules: true,
    import: true,
    lessLoaderOptions: {
      javascriptEnabled: true,
    },
    cssLoaderOptions: {
      localIdentName: "[local]",
    },
    env: {
      CAMP_PHONE: process.env.CAMP_PHONE,
      HOST: process.env.HOST,
      PORT: process.env.PORT
    }
   })
);
```

Most relevant package.json deps, can give entire list if wanted for error-testing:

```js
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-less": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.7.0",
    "nav-frontend-lenker-style": "^0.2.20",
    "next": "^9.0.1",
    "next-images": "^1.1.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "url-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.35.2"
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1"
```

I expect the less import to import the relevant files and bundle them accordingly.

This is the error message I get, when running `next build`:

```
> Build error occurred
/Users/Username/PathToRepo/node_modules/nav-frontend-lenker-style/src/lenker-style.less:1
@import './lenker-mixins';
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Username/PathToRepo/node_modules/nav-frontend-lenker/lib/lenke.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Thanks in advance for anyone willing to help :)

Comment: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/1044

Answer (score 2):

Ref: https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/267

Adding these lines of code below the require statements, removed the issue

```
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.less'] = () => {};
}
```